# GCC linker script

Tags: c, gcc, arm, pragma, linker-scripts

So I have an old code written for ARM compiler with many `#pragma` for assigning variables and functions to sections like this:

```
...thousands lines of code
  #pragma arm section blah = "blah"
...thousands lines of code
  #pragma arm section
...thousands lines of code
```

I know I could use the `__attribute__(section("name"))` instead but I have to copy and paste this for every line. I am new to the GCC linker script so I am just wondering if I can embed special linker symbols or something in the code and then later ask the linker to place anything between those symbols in a certain section. Is there anything like that in GCC?

Comment: Can you split the old code up into multiple source files without breaking anything?  GNU linker scripts can assign the contents of an entire *object file* to a specific (group of) sections, but I don't think there's any direct equivalent of the armcc feature you're talking about.

Comment: @zwol No splitting into multiple files is even more work and requires multiple teams to work on it. I am using the linker script to cover those pragmas that are used for an entire file but some files like the example above has multiple code segments with pragma sections... it is a real hassle!

Comment: In that case, I'm sorry, I don't have a better suggestion for you.